# What memory management is appropriate for a UITableViewRowAction closure?

Tags: swift, memory-management, closures

Is my use of unowned for self and neither weak nor unowned for tableView appropriate in the following context?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [unowned self] (action, indexPath) in
        self.habitsManager.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.adjustForRowCount()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    return [delete]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need any `capture list` in this situation.

The time when use capture list is when we would create a strong reference cycle, which means those objects are pointing to each other and ARC would consider them still in use since the count isn't `0`.

In `editActionsForRowAt` situation, the closure is not pointing to anything else, just a block of code to be executed.

> Tapping one of the action buttons executes the handler block stored with the action object.

Read more about `editActionsForRowAt` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614956-tableview)

In conclusion, it's safe to remove `[unowned self]` and because you're not using `action`, you could replace it by `_` to make it bit cleaner. And you don't have to call `tableView.reloadData()` here as well.

```
let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {(_, indexPath) in
    self.habitsManager.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.adjustForRowCount()
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

By the way, Swift document has some great examples of how ARC works and when to use capture list. You may check it out as well. [Link](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_61)